# How do I synchronize scroll in two RichTextBoxes maintaining a ratio?

Tags: c#, .net, scroll, richtextbox

I found out a code online here, in StackOverflow itself:
[How can I sync the scrolling of two multiline textboxes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823188/how-can-i-sync-the-scrolling-of-two-multiline-textboxes)

It works fine, but I want a proportional scrolling. This means that, if I have two `RichTextBoxes`, `RichTextBox1` having 10 lines and `RichTextBox2` having 100 lines, so when I scroll in `RichTextBox1` it will jump 10 lines in `RichTextBox2` for every 1 line of scrolling and if I scroll in `RichTextBox2` it will scroll 1 line in `RichTextBox1` for every 10 lines in `RichTextBox2`.

I think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are better ways to do it (without meddling with the selection) but this seems to work:

```
class myRTB : RichTextBox
{
    public myRTB()
    {
        this.Multiline = true;
        this.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
    }

    public myRTB Buddy { get; set; }

    private static bool scrolling;   // In case buddy tries to scroll us
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        // Trap WM_VSCROLL message and pass to buddy
        if (m.Msg == 0x115 && !scrolling && Buddy != null && Buddy.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            scrolling = true;
            synchTopLineRel(Buddy);
            scrolling = false;
        }
    }

    void synchTopLineRel(RichTextBox rtb)
    {
        int i0 = GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point.Empty);
        int i1 = GetLineFromCharIndex(i0);
        int i2 = (int)(i1 * Buddy.Lines.Length / Lines.Length);
        // the rest scrolls to line # i2..:
        int bss = Buddy.SelectionStart;
        int bsl = Buddy.SelectionLength;
        Buddy.SelectionStart = Buddy.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i2);
        Buddy.ScrollToCaret();
        Buddy.SelectionStart = bss;
        Buddy.SelectionLength = bsl;
    }
}
```

Note that is has no error checks and will do a very simple calculation. It will not work well with:

- RTBs with different Fonts
- RTBs with different sizes

Especially if you need to code the `ScelectionChanged` event you will prefer to replace the scrolling with a proper call to [SetScrollPos](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setscrollpos). Possible [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380104/c-setscrollpos-user32-dll)